# Delete some lines from text using Linux command

Tags: linux, shell, sed, grep, pattern-matching

I know how to match text using [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) patterns but not how to manipulate them.

I have used [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) to match and extract lines from a text file, but I want to remove those lines from the text. How can I achieve this without having to write a [python](/questions/tagged/python) or [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) shell script?

I have searched on Google and was recommended to use [sed](/questions/tagged/sed), but I am new to it and don't know how it works.

Can anyone point me in the right direction or help me achieve this goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-v` option to `grep` inverts the search, reporting only the lines that don't match the pattern.

Since you know how to use `grep` to find the lines to be deleted, using `grep -v` and the same pattern will give you all the lines to be kept.  You can write that to a temporary file and then copy or move the temporary file over the original.

```
grep -v pattern original.file > tmp.file
mv tmp.file original.file
```

You can also use `sed`, as shown in [shellfish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1775715/shellfish)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30991383/15168).

There are multiple possible refinements for the `grep` solution, but for most people most of the time, what is shown is more or less adequate (it would be a good idea to use a per process intermediate file name, preferably with a random name such as the `mktemp` command gives you).  You can add code to remove the intermediate file on an interrupt; suppress interrupts while moving back; use copy and remove instead of move if the original file has multiple hard links or is a symlink; etc.  The `sed` command more or less works around these issues for you, but it is not cognizant of multiple hard links or symlinks.

Comment: Of course, `grep -v`, such an elegant answer. Should have thought about that!

Comment: I have achieved it using `grep -v`. That works well.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Create the pattern which matches the lines using [grep](/questions/tagged/grep). Then create a [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) script as follows:

```
sed -i '/pattern/d' file
```

Explanation:

- The `-i` option means overwrite the input file, thus removing the files matching `pattern`.
- `pattern` is the pattern you created for `grep`, e.g. `^a*b\+`.
- `d` this sed command stands for delete, it will delete lines matching the pattern.
- `file` this is the input file, it can consist of a relative or absolute path.

For more information see `man sed`.

Comment: Note that `sed` does not recognize `+` as a regex metacharacter by default, even with GNU `sed`.  The sample pattern matches `b+`, `aab+`, but not `aaabc`.  Add the `-r` option to enable extended regexes.

Comment: Of course, I was being sloppy. I just gave some random pattern off the top of my head. Thanks for pointing that out though!